# Measuring perplexity over a limited domain in an LLM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, recommender-system, perplexity, llm

Are there papers/a literature on measuring perplexity in using a Large Language Model such as ChatGPT/Flan over a limited domain?

I want to prompt an LLM to do movie recommendations/next job prediction and such, and these models are often compared using loglikelihood/perplexity. There is a lot of work doing recommendations and measuring AUROC or ranking metrics like NDCG, but nothing reports loglikelihood over test set or preplexity. The challenge here would be to measure perplexity over a limited domain and over multiple tokens (not simply next token).

Comment: Measuring perplexity over multiple tokens isn't intrinsically hard: compare the probabilities of the two strings. More interesting is this "limited domain"—do you have a finite set of movies a priori?

Comment: Yes, I do have a limited set of movies.

Answer (score 1):

A language model is a probability distribution over strings. These strings are sequences of tokens from some vocabulary $\Sigma$ plus a special end-of-sequence symbol $\textrm{EOS}$. Every string $\mathbf{x}=w_1w_2\ldots w_n \textrm{EOS}$ has a probability that is expressible with the chain rule:
\begin{equation}
p(\mathbf{x}) = p(w_1)\cdot p(w_2 \mid w_1) \cdot \ldots \cdot p(\textrm{EOS} \mid w_1w_2\ldots w_n)
\text{.}
\end{equation}

You've said that you have a finite set of movie titles, so you have a finite set of strings $\mathcal{X} \subset \Sigma^*$. In this circumstance, you can renormalize the probability over that finite set:
\begin{equation}
p'(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{p(\mathbf{x})}{\sum_{\mathbf{x'} \in \mathcal{X}} p(\mathbf{x}')}
\text{.}
\end{equation}

Now that we have a distribution over your set of movie titles, it's straightforward to compute the cross-entropy using the standard formula.

Comment: This is useful, but there are two follow ups. One - is this chain rule 'fair' - would you not discount longer names unfairly and Two - this is computationally really expensive (for me infeasible) as we need to get estimates for ALL movies in our vocabulary this way.